# Images flickering in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-intent

I am working on social application and it's about to complete but I got stuck on one issue that is image flickering. When there is around 9 to 10 images on screen and if I scroll the page then the image flicker take place.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.view_grid_explore, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_grid_album);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
            Static_Urls.explore_pic + data.get(position).talk_pic,
            holder.img);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Remove the notifyDataSetChanged() line first..

Comment: Thanks Mike its working .

Answer (score 0):

- Note : Don't forget to remove `notifyDataSetChanged();`.

This is happening because once the images are downloaded in the device by UIL(Universal Image Loader), it caches the images in Memory and device.

By using this code :

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Static_Urls.explore_pic +data.get(position).talk_pic,
            holder.img);
```

every time `getView()` is called UIL tries to fetch the image from network, but by the time it releases that image is already being cached so it shows the image after making a network request first.

so in order to get rid of this flickering use this code :

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        File file = imageLoader.getDiskCache().get(Static_Urls.explore_pic +data.get(position).talk_pic);
        if (file==null) {
            //Load image from network
             imageLoader.displayImage(Static_Urls.explore_pic +data.get(position).talk_pic,
            holder.img); 
        }
        else {
           //Load image from cache
            holder.img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
```

This code will first check whether the image is already cached or not, Then accordingly fetch image from Network or from cache.

Comment: which UIL version are you using.

Comment: libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3-with-sources.jar using this

Comment: `getDiscCache()` is working fine with this solution. Try importing the UIL library using `Gradle` compile code.

Comment: am using getDiscCache() but same issue

Answer (score 0):

The `notifyDataSetChanged()` line is redundant there. Working with adapters always keep in mind that(in case of adapters extending BaseAdapter) the `getView()` method is responsible for inflating the layout of the list item and also updating the UI if if you handle it so(normally you do)

Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` will cause the `getView()` being called again right away which is why you see the flickering.

You should only call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when you would like to update the adapter content. One example would be when you build yourself a "refresh()" method inside your adapter like:

```
public void refresh(List<Object> list) {
    data.clear();// Assuming data is a List<> object or an implementation of it like ArrayList();
    data.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // This will let the adapter know that something changed in the adapter and this change should be reflected on the UI too, thus the getView() method will be called implicitly.
}
```